# Relative path names VB2010

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a little Jukebox application in VB Forms, and I need the pathnames of the sound files (\bin\Tracks\"Insert Name Here") to be relative instead of absolute, so that it may work on a different computer to mine. At the moment, I am testing with the simple Soundplayer class, and the single line of code to play a song is this:

My.Computer.Audio.Play("\bin\Tracks\" & txtCurrentlyPlaying.Text)

It works when, instead of \bin\Tracks\, I put the full pathname (C:\Documents And Settings etc.), but not when I try a relative path such as this. Can anybody help?
Thank you for your time.
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, txtCurrentlyPlaying.Text)`

Comment: It still errors, saying "make sure there is a sound file at this location". I tried adding \bin\ and \tracks\ or both to it as well, still nothing. Thanks for that snippet though, very useful for the future

Comment: Look at value of Environment.CurrentDirectory when debugging, then append the appropriate relative path.